# Python Nested JSON Data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, suds

This script has been working for over a year, however it has now stopped.

The JSON data looks like this,

```
(The_Data){
         Date = "06Jan2015"
         Nested_data[] = 
            (information){
               animal = "dog"
               colour = "white"},
            (information){
               animal = "cat"
               colour = "ginger"},
            }
```

This line below previously worked to display all of the data within Nested_data[], however it now returns

[suds.sudsobject.RecordJobNumberRecord object at 0x000001802E564488]

```
print (JSON_data['The_Data']['Nested_data'])
```

Oddly the line below still returns the first part of the Nested Data, "information animal = dog colour = white",

```
print (JSON_data['The_Data']['Nested_data'][0])
```

Comment: this cant' be the json data. Looks like something exported. JSON would look like {"Key":"value"}

Comment: I think I've found the issue. The WSDL now species type as "tns1", previously is said type="xsd:string". Not sure what I need to change but I think that's where the issue is.